# Is Cassandra the best way to build a reporting system

Tags: mysql, cassandra, reporting

I will summarize my case below:

I am trying to add an authentication user information in Cassandra. It Actually works fine for the basics like authenticate user, add new user, check user login, edit and delete account.

But after I built that we, tried to apply reporting system using Cassandra storage like

- get total user
- get number of users based on registration time filter
- get number of users based on login time filter
- get number of users based on gender
- get number of users based verification email
- search users based on email,first name and last name
- like search
- get number of users based on registration language
- and other criteria come up upon product manager

based on what I have seen I think its fine to move my reporting to MySql and keep my system working based on Cassandra.

I will use a proper way to sync data from Cassandra to MySql.

Answer (score 2):

Since Cassandra 3.4 (released today), you can use the new SASI index for full text search capabilities in Cassandra. It seems to meet your requirement of dynamic search:

Preview of full text search: https://twitter.com/doanduyhai/status/707231879456546816

Official doc to use this full text search index: https://twitter.com/doanduyhai/status/707232855873732609

Be careful that some use-case may not benefit at all from this new index, for example the use-case "get number of users based verification email".

The simple reason is that for 1 email address, you'll have at maximum 1 user (because of email unicity per user). So even with the new index, in the **worst case**, you'll need to scan all the nodes in the cluster (modulo replication factor) to find the user matching your email.

For such 1 to 1 relationship (between user and email), it's better to use materialized view, read my blog about it: [www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=1930](http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=1930)

Comment: I've read through that article of yours and it is very good.  Nicely done!